# PHP get largest number from mysql table

Tags: php, mysql

i have counted the number of voters that voted for certain candidate i want to display which one got the highest voting number. i tried to store them in variables so i can use max() method but i got the error "undefined ".any help please

```
  <?php 
 $query="select count(*) as total from voting Where ca_id=1";
  //ca_id is the candidate id that voter choose
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo"$row[total]<br>";


 $query="select count(*) as total2 from voting Where ca_id=2";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo"$row2[total2]<br>";

 $query="select count(*) as total3 from voting Where ca_id=3";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $row3 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo"$row3[total3]<br>";

 $query="select count(*) as total4 from voting Where ca_id=5";
 $result = mysql_query($query);
 $row4 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 echo"$row4[total4]<br>";



?>
```

Comment: [Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: It would be easier for us to help you if you set up a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/)

Comment: dump your values into an array and use asort() or arsort()

Comment: How did you try to "store them in variables"?

Comment: Let the database calculate it! `SUM()` and `GROUP BY`...

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to perform four queries for this. You could just use a single query. In your case, you could do:

```
select ca_id, count(*) as counter from voting group by ca_id order by counter desc
```

And you can get your result with a single query

As mentioned, PDO is a better alternative in this case for your database-related calls

Comment: i have different IDs and they are repeated more than once
so i want to count number of duplication for each id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT count(1) co, ca_id FROM voting GROUP BY ca_id ORDER BY co DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 2):

> [Please, don't use mysql_* functions in new code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-function-in-php) They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://news.php.net/php.internals/53799) has begun on it. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli) - this [article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

You could use something like which uses the MySQLi extension.

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('host', 'user', 'pass', 'db');

$sql   = "SELECT COUNT(votes) as vote_count, ca_id as candidate_id FROM voting GROUP BY ca_id ORDER BY vote_count DESC";
$result= $mysqli -> query($sql);

// Error Checking
if($mysqli -> error){
   echo 'Error: '.$mysqli -> error;
   exit;
}

while($row = $result -> fetch_object()){
   
   // Print out each candidate ID and the amount of votes they had.
   echo 'Candidate ID: '.$row -> candidate_id.', Votes: '.$row -> vote_count.'<br/>';

   // If you want to just show the highest voted candidate - put the data in an array
   $votes[$row -> vote_count] = $row -> candidate_id;

}

echo max(array_keys($votes));
```

This will also cut the amount of queries your running down to just 1.

Comment: i got this error
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object

Comment: Have you changed the DB connection settings so they connect to your DB? Also, i've added a few lines that will print out any error message.

Answer (score 0):

first of all use group by to retrieve all data in one query, instead of querying for each of the candidates:

```
SELECT ca_id, count(*) as total FROM voting GROUP BY ca_id
```

if you need a top voted id use:

```
SELECT ca_id, count(*) as total FROM voting GROUP BY ca_id SORT BY total 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

Note: not the most efficient solution but will be way faster then querying for each ca_id.

Comment: i used this one "SELECT ca_id, count(*) as total FROM voting GROUP BY ca_id" that you gave me but it didn't give the total voting for each candidate"i have 5 candidate".